# CTE Linking on Different ID Fields

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I'm trying to create a SQL query that obtains data from 3 different tables.  My thought was to use a CTE to gather the information from 2 tables, and then do a right join to add in the data into the rest of my query.  I need to bring in disparate data from each field but am running into the infamous error `multi-part identifier could not be bound`  Here's what I've written so far:

```
with cte1 as
(
SELECT          
[Physician ID] as InternalIdentifier, NPI, [Last Name] as LastName, [First Name]     
as     
FirstName,
Physician_T1HYCPP.Specialty, DOB, Degree, Department, [State License Number], [UPIN Number],    
[Physician Status]
FROM  Physician_T1HYCPP left outer JOIN PhysicianFile 
on Physician_T1HYCPP.[Physician ID] = PhysicianFile.[TSI MD Number]
where NPI <> ''
),
cteView
AS
(
Select [Doctor_Number], Address, City, State, Zip, Phone, Fax
from V_PhysicianList
)
Select 
InternalIdentifier, NPI, LastName, FirstName,
Specialty, DOB, Degree, Department, [State License Number], [UPIN Number],
[Physician Status],     
[Doctor_Number],
Address,City, State, Zip, Phone, Fax
from cte1
right outer join cteView on
V_PhysicianList.[Doctor_Number] = PhysicianFile.[Doctor Number]
```

Here are the specific errors:

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "V_PhysicianList.Doctor_Number" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "PhysicianFile.Doctor Number" could not be bound.
```

The goal here is to bring in all the fields from the 2 tables in the first CTE and then "merge" in the fields from the second CTE so that address etc. get valued in the end result set.  How can I ensure that fields from both cte1 and cteView are merged properly?

Comment: Can you post the exact error message, including numbers.

Comment: A little indentation would go a long way here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the SELECT at the end you select from the CTEs but reference the base table in the JOIN clause. Just use the correct prefix:

```
Select 
InternalIdentifier, NPI, LastName, FirstName,
Specialty, DOB, Degree, Department, [State License Number], [UPIN Number],
[Physician Status],     
[Doctor_Number],
Address,City, State, Zip, Phone, Fax
from cte1
right outer join cteView on
cteView.[Doctor_Number] = cte1.[Doctor Number]
```

However, you also need to include that column in the cte1. During the final select SQL Server has only access to tables, views or CTEs mentioned in there, so it cannot resolve the reference to the base table.